# Choosing Hazelcast features

Tags: java, hashmap, distributed, hazelcast

I have a task (i describe it a bit later) and as far as I understand, Hazelcast is a best choice for it. But it has so many features and usages, so I can't understand what exactly to choose.

Actually the task is: 
I have Java server app A and Java server app B. I have several Java servers, some of them holding A app instance, some of them holding B instance, some holding both.

I need to store one map between all servers. Both A and B can put in map, and B can read from the map by key.

So I think I need a distributed map, but I cant understand what other features do I need? What will be a backup configuration? Do I need distributed query for B to lookup by key? Do I need a "Hazelcast client"?

Answer (score 2):

Hazelcast is a great tool. Agree it can be daunting to see what you need, but it's simpler than you think :)

You first need to run one or more Hazelcast nodes to get your grid running (recommend 2 or more to give redundancy).

It's up to you if server A/B have embedded hazelcast nodes, or if you run a hazelcast grid externally to server A/B and use HazelcastClient to talk to it.

You're best placed to evaluate this decision. It's probably easier to start by embedding a hazelcast grid node into server A/B. If you find it doesn't work for you, run a separate hazelcast grid and switch to using HazelcastClient in server A/B.

You will need to configure some ports for your grid to run on, the most common configuration is localhost:5701, and incremental ports up from here (5702, 5703, etc).

To distribute your data, this is dead easy - configure a hazelcast Map, give it a name, and set the backup count (a value of 1 would be fine).

I can't see that you need a distributed query here, since `IMap<K,V>` should give you access to the data you need.

Does this help? Do you have further specific questions?

The Hazelcast documentation is rather good and there is also an active user community.

Good luck!

Comment: The point about node vs client was exactly what I wondered.... the answer - try it..?

Comment: Exactly, and see what suits your situation best. If you find, say, that you have 3 stable jvms running already, then it might make sense to embed the Hazelcast instance into each of them. Otherwise, it's very easy to run an external grid of {x} nodes and talk to it via HazelcastClient. Nowadays I tend to take the latter case, but in the beginning I found the former case easier.

Answer (score 0):

Steve! Thank you very mach for your answer. Finally in my logic class i created a singleton to work with Hazelcast instance - like

```
final static String DistributedMapName = "SystemUserActivityMap";
private static HazelcastInstance instance = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();
```

I also created a hazelcast.xml, pretty simple

```
 <network>
            <port auto-increment="true">5701</port>
            <join>
                <multicast enabled="false">
                    <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
                    <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
                </multicast>
                <tcp-ip enabled="true">
                    <interface>127.0.0.1</interface>
                </tcp-ip>
                <aws enabled="false">
                </aws>
            </join>
        </network>
    <map name="SystemUserActivityMap">...
```

everything seemed to working fine at first, but later i noticed in tomcat errorlog messages that hazelcast starts new port from time to time, so soon after start it was

```
Members [1] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5701 this
}
```

now its

```
Members [9] {
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5701
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5702
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5703
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5704
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5705
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5706
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5707 this
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5708
    Member [127.0.0.1]:5709
}
```

and continue growing...
i don't understand why it uses all these ports on this machine

Comment: Mikhail, have you deployed the web app to tomcat multiple times? And did you undeploy and deploy in tomcat manager or via autodeploy (or how)? I have a feeling you could have a memory / thread leak when you undeploy and the hazelcast instance isn't shut down. What happens if you completely restart tomcat? Please test that and let me know the result.